# How to configure Fedora / RedHat / CentOS to delete files in /tmp on boot

Tags: centos, redhat, fedora

How can you configure Fedora / RedHat / CentOS systems to delete files in /tmp on boot like Debian and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7):

On recent versions (CentOS 7, Fedora 23), add a .conf file to "/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d", the name is irrelevant, name it boot.conf for example, but it has to be a different file than tmp.conf, there cannot be two entries for the same directory in a single file. Add the the following line:

```
R! /tmp 1777 root root ~0
```

Comment: As an admin you should not be adding files to `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d`; files in that directory and `/usr/lib` in general are intended to be installed by the package. To add or override behavior add .conf file to `/etc/tmpfiles.d`. Files of the `/etc/tmpfiles.d` override files of the same name in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d`. See `man tmpfiles.d` for details: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html

Comment: Can you add an explanation of each of the parts of the line you suggested adding to the .conf file?

Answer (score 2):

By default `/tmp` is a tmpfs, and doesn't exist on boot anyway. To get into this situation, your server must already be non-standard in some way: Someone explicitly configured your system to *not* have `/tmp` emptied on boot.

So it is best to fix the problem, by undoing whatever changes were made to cause `/tmp` to not mount as a tmpfs on boot:

1. Make sure the mount has not been disabled:

   ```
   systemctl unmask tmp.mount
   ```

   If this command fails, fix the problem before continuing.
2. Go to single user mode. You need to be on the console for this.

   ```
   systemctl start rescue.target
   ```
3. Empty the `/tmp` directory on the hard drive, to clear out the used space.

   ```
   rm -rf /tmp
   mkdir -m 1777 /tmp
   ```
4. On CentOS 7, you need to explicitly enable the mount. On Fedora, you can skip this.

   ```
   systemctl enable tmp.mount
   ```
5. Restart the system.

   ```
   systemctl start default.target
   ```

Comment: As of CentOS 7, /tmp is not a tmpfs by default, some people still have to deal with that version and might need to clear /tmp on reboot. I disagree with the idea that /tmp should be a tmpfs, but recognize there is space for both schools of thought.

Comment: As of an update in CentOS 7 (I believe somewhere in 7.2) while /tmp is a filesystem, each user by default gets a tmpfs overlay specific to their UID.  Just adding for completeness sake.

Comment: @YvesDorfsman It exists on my 7.2 systems. But it was disabled by default. It needed some extra steps to be enabled.